# Why is my data not being submitted into my database?

Tags: php, sql, database-connection

I need to connect an html form to my sql database and I'm starting out with a simple form so I can understand how it works. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have the form created, the php script, and the database created. Whenever I submit the form it takes me to a blank page and nothing has been added to my database. I've written error messages if the connections fail but I'm not seeing those either. I'm not as advanced in programming can someone please help me?

index1.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="info.php" method="post">

<p>Username:<input type="text" name="username" /></p>
<p>Email:<input type="text" name="email" /></p>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>


</form>

 </body>
</html>
```

info.php

```
 <?php

define('DB_NAME' , 'users' );
define('DB_USER' , 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD' , '');
define('DB_HOST' , 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
//connection to host
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//error if not connected to host

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
//select the database

if(!$db_selected){
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ':' . mysql_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

$value = $_POST['username'];
$value2 = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO guests (username, email) VALUES ('$value', '$value2')";

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
//error check to see if connected to tables

mysql_close();
//close connection
?>
```

Comment: Your code checks out. I'm betting you'll need to use `mysqli_` or PDO. Error reporting will tell you that. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Don't forget to securise your code : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: You should turn on the error reporting.

Comment: Use $sql = "INSERT INTO guests (username, email) VALUES ('".$value."', '".$value2."')";

Comment: @sgtBOSE My head is spinning. How's yours?

Comment: Feeling the same. ha ha ha... @Fred-ii-

Comment: If you are able to use `mysql_` functions, then the only other possible reason here would be because you're entering characters that MySQL isn't agreeing with, such as quotes. I.e.: `John's Catering`. But even then, a "blank screen" means errors elsewhere and since you're using `mysql_error()` on your query, then that should have thrown you a syntax error if that were the case. Also make sure your server is properly configured for PHP/MySQL/Apache. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php will also help with this.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in comments; your `mysql_` code checks out, so chances are you need to use either `mysqli_` or PDO, since `mysql_` functions may very well not be available for you to use.

If the following `mysqli_` rewrite does not work for you, then the problem goes deeper and would be out of scope of the question.

Using [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) will/should confirm that. Consult "Footnotes" on how to use it in your PHP file(s).

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME' , 'users' );
define('DB_USER' , 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD' , '');
define('DB_HOST' , 'localhost');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
//connection to host
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}


echo 'Connected successfully';

$value = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['username']);
$value2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO guests (username, email) VALUES ('$value', '$value2')";

if(!mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
//error check to see if connected to tables

else{
echo "Data entered";
}

mysqli_close($link);
//close connection
?>
```

---

References:

- MySQLi: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php
- Error reporting: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

**Footnotes:**

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

- Make sure your server is running and properly configured for PHP/MySQL/Apache.
- Make sure your columns are indeed `VARCHAR` and long enough to accommodate the data.

Answer (score -1):

Try this query:

`INSERT INTO guest set username=$value1,email=$value2`

hope it will solve .

Comment: no, this is even worse. Plus, we're dealing with strings here

Comment: there is no problem in that query @sgt since using the same it was not able to perform insert operation which is why i suggest to try different query it might help

Comment: So what you think? Is it an answer or comment?

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO guests (username, email) VALUES ($value, $value2)"; Then add var_dump($sql); and paste the content here. Do you have maybe quote or double quote making the insert fails...

Comment: have you tried echoing both the post value . Is it posting correctly? -- @Fred

Comment: I don't need to; I know.

Comment: you can try using .(dot) opreater and concatinate the variable with the sql string instead of directly writing it like for eg:-

`"insert into guest" (username,email) values(".$value1.",".$value.")`

hope this might help

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it should work for you.

$sql = "INSERT INTO guests (username, email) VALUES (".$value.", ".$value2.")";

Comment: this is even worse also.